# How to set the width of a jquery mobile slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, slider

```
myScroller.scoller("refresh", {width:5}); would be fantastic
```

Here's what I've got. This works pretty good (a little off but screw it). The problem is the little slider ball thinks it has the entire original width so it slides off the bar.

```
$.each($(":jqmData(role=fieldcontain) > div[class~='ui-slider']"), function () {
    var slider = $(this);
    slider.css("width", (slider.width() - 16) + "px !important");
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just select the slider widgets and set their widths without a loop:

```
//set all slider widgets to 250px wide
$('.ui-slider').width(250);

//set all slider widgets to 50% wide
$('.ui-slider').width('50%');

//set all slider widgets to 25px less than their current width
$('.ui-slider').width(function (i, old_width) {
    return old_width - 25;
});
```

I would place this code in a `pageinit` handler like so:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '.ui-page', function () {
    $(this).find('.ui-slider').width(250);
});
```

Comment: In the actual code there is some processing going on that needs the loop. It turns out the problem was from a margin-left on the bar. I didn't notice until I made this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4rnUC/ which works as expected.